# Manually decoding the Size presend on a CodedInputStream

Tags: c#, .net-core, protocol-buffers

So I have a dotNet CoreCLR application for hololens and it's my understanding that standard sockets aren't supported in CoreCLR and the recommended avenue is to use `StreamSocket`.

It's also my understanding that `CodedInputStream` and `StreamSocket` aren't compatible.

So I've been manually trying to decode the size pre-send but it's a varInt32 which can be anything from 2-4 bytes.

This is as far as I've gotten but that variable size issue is giving me problems.

```
int bytenum = 0;
int num = 0;
while((bytes[bytenum] & 0x80) == 0x80){
    bytenum++;
}
while(bytenum >= 0)
{
    int tem = bytes[bytenum] & 0x7F;
    num = num << 7;
    num = num | tem;
    bytenum--;
}
```

Any suggestions on how I might fix this code or alternatives I might use?

Edit: I've also had a look at the [CodedInputStream.cs](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/CodedInputStream.cs) SlowReadRawVarint32() and tried this with no success... I'm thinking the DataReader is doing something non-standard.

```
var dr = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);

await dr.LoadAsync(1);

int result = -1;
int tmp = dr.ReadByte();

if (tmp >= 128)
{
    result = tmp & 0x7f;
    await dr.LoadAsync(1);
    if ((tmp = dr.ReadByte()) < 128)
    {
        result |= tmp << 7;
    }
    else
    {

        result |= (tmp & 0x7f) << 7;
        await dr.LoadAsync(1);
        if ((tmp = dr.ReadByte()) < 128)
        {
            result |= tmp << 14;
        }
        else
        {
            result |= (tmp & 0x7f) << 14;
            await dr.LoadAsync(1);
            if ((tmp = dr.ReadByte()) < 128)
            {
                result |= tmp << 21;
            }
            else
            {
                result |= (tmp & 0x7f) << 21;
                await dr.LoadAsync(1);
                result |= (tmp = dr.ReadByte()) << 28;
                if (tmp >= 128)
                {
                    // Discard upper 32 bits.
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        await dr.LoadAsync(1);
                        if (dr.ReadByte() < 128)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    result = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Note: You seem to not always set `isGoodResult = true;` where you should.

Comment: I believe that's a red herring... Even if I pull that out I'm getting presend lengths that are low to presend lengths that are about 40 times larger than expected.

Comment: What evidence do you have that the solutions you have tried do not work. Is there anything you can provide that will help determine whether a given solution is correct or not?

Comment: Well CodedInputStreams are a Protobuf feature. I have a java app that printlns the length that I'm connecting into and the first presend decode is a mixed bag on if it decodes correctly and gives me the correct length but after that it fails 100% of the time.
I'm assuming my bit math is off somehow or the DataReader is incorrectly interpreting the data somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code looks oddly similar, although a bit off at times to (https://github.com/deephacks/westty/blob/master/westty-protobuf/src/main/java/org/deephacks/westty/protobuf/Varint32.java) have you seen it? Are you trying to translate it?

```
public int read() throws IOException {

byte tmp = bytes.get();
if (tmp >= 0) {
        return tmp;
    }
    int result = tmp & 0x7f;
    if ((tmp = bytes.get()) >= 0) {
        result |= tmp << 7;
    } else {
        result |= (tmp & 0x7f) << 7;
        if ((tmp = bytes.get()) >= 0) {
            result |= tmp << 14;
        } else {
            result |= (tmp & 0x7f) << 14;
            if ((tmp = bytes.get()) >= 0) {
                result |= tmp << 21;
            } else {
                result |= (tmp & 0x7f) << 21;
                result |= (tmp = bytes.get()) << 28;
                if (tmp < 0) {
                    // Discard upper 32 bits.
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        if (bytes.get() >= 0) {
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If not, perhaps you could use it as inspiration. Since your values are 40 times larger than expected, I suspect shifting errors. If you do not solve it, I can help further by translating that class for you, but it is a big time investment!